# Accessing nested arrays in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to access a nested array inside html code using smarty. For example i have an array that looks like this: Array(customer)[name, age, id[firstname, lastname, birthdate]]. I have been trying something like this:

```
{foreach from=$customer item=foo} 
    Customer id: {$foo.id} 
{/foreach}
```

But this doesent print any values to the page. 
However with this syntax

```
{foreach from $customer item=foo}
    {$foo.id} // or {$foo.id.0}
{/foreach}
```

It prints out: Array

How do i access the values of nested array using smarty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{foreach from=$customer item=foo} 
    Customer name: {$foo.id.firstname} {$foo.id.lastname}
{/foreach}
```

`Smarty` will compile it to something equivalent with:

```
foreach ($customer as $foo) {
   echo('Customer name: '.$foo['id']['firstname'].' '.$foo['id']['laststname']);
}
```

Comment: When i try to do it this way it doesent print out any values, do i have to include all the values in the nested array, for example if  i just want the firstname? Or do i have a problem in the array?

Comment: I tried to guess using the scarce information you provided. Show us a `print_r()` of your array and how do you assign it to `Smarty`.

Comment: I put the PHP equivalent of the Smarty code. Does it work? Maybe the structure of your array is different. Make it work using PHP then, using my example, write the equivalent Smarty text. Read the Smarty [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/) about [variables](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) and [`{foreach}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl)

Comment: Array ([0] => Array ([customer] => [Age] => 18 [id] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [firstname] => bob [lastname] => test)))

Comment: Your structure has unneeded nesting levels but it's your design, maybe you have your reasons to do it so. The `PHP` code needed to display the customers' names seems to be `foreach ($customer as $item) echo($item['id'][0]['firstname']);` and so on. You should be able to figure out the Smarty code now.

Answer (score 0):

Your $foo.id is an actual array, so you should iterate over it as well.

```
{foreach from=$customer item=foo} 
    Contained values: {$foo.id.firstname} {$foo.id.lastname} {$foo.id.birthdate}
{/foreach}
```